# Android Studio custom gradle task with dependencies - "Could not get unknown property"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using a library that supplies gradle tasks to upload builds to HockeyApp (https://github.com/x2on/gradle-hockeyapp-plugin).  I think what it does specifically isn't important, just that it creates tasks.  I can run those tasks no problem.  I wanted to create a task to run several of these custom tasks at once.  The upload tasks are named like `upload[BuildVariant]ToHockeyApp` and it created one for each build variant.  My custom task, defined in `android` in the project level gradle file, looks like this:

```
task uploadLegacyReleaseToHockeyApp(dependsOn:
            uploadVariant1ReleaseToHockeyApp,
            uploadVariant2ReleaseToHockeyApp,
            // etc
      ){}
```

When syncing the gradle file, I get this error:

`Error:(89, 0) Could not get unknown property 'uploadVariant1ReleaseToHockeyApp' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.`

I've triple checked there are no typos and the task in the error message actually exists. Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to write a dependency on a task that's dynamically generated like this?  I don't really know how the plugin works, but it creates its own task group with automatically generated tasks in it.

**UPDATE based on the answer from lukegv:**

If I use the `dependsOn` method I get this error: `Error:(90, 0) Could not get unknown property 'uploadVariant1ToHockeyApp' for task ':app:uploadLegacyReleaseToHockeyApp' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.`

With the constructor:

```
task uploadLegacyReleaseToHockeyApp(dependsOn:
            'uploadVariant1ToHockeyApp',
            'uploadVariant2ToHockeyApp',
            // etc
```

I got this: `Could not find method uploadLegacyReleaseToHockeyApp() for arguments [{dependsOn=uploadVariant1ToHockeyApp}, uploadVariant2ToHockeyApp,...`

Note the first item is in curly braces and the rest are not.

If I put all the task names in a single string, it successfully syncs the build files, but the string is interpreted as a single task name so running it fails.

Comment: Did you also use strings with the `dependsOn` method? Normally, you should not get a "Could not get unknown property" error when using strings. Did you try my minimal example?

Comment: I think I used strings but I don't remember for certain.  I didn't try your example since I don't directly control the generated tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle distinguishes between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. In the *configuration phase*, Gradle evaluates (by executing) the whole build script and afterwards it builds a task dependency tree. In the *execution phase*, Gradle executes the tasks specified via command line and their dependencies.

Since it is possible to add or define things like variants over the whole build script, generated tasks are often created at the end of the *configuration phase*, so that they are not available as properties in the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) scope during configuration.

However, you can define a task dependency by specifying a task name as String. This way, a dependency is registered and the subsequently generated task will be used after the *configuration phase*, when the dependency tree is built.

As a example:

```
task t1 {
    dependsOn t2        // this fails
    dependsOn 't2'      // this works, even if t2 does not exist right now
}

afterEvaluate {
    task t2 {}
}
```

To solve your specific problem, specify your task dependency as String containing the task name:

```
task uploadLegacyReleaseToHockeyApp {
    dependsOn 'uploadVariant1ReleaseToHockeyApp'
    dependsOn 'uploadVariant2ReleaseToHockeyApp'
}
```

I am using the `dependsOn` method instead of the `dependsOn` map key in the constructor, because I think its more elegant that way, however you can also just edit your code to use a list of Strings:

```
task uploadLegacyReleaseToHockeyApp(dependsOn: ['uploadVariant1ReleaseToHockeyApp', 'uploadVariant2ReleaseToHockeyApp']) {
    // configuration
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I edited the question with the results since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: If you want to update your answer to incorporate what I posted in mine I can mark it correct.  Right now it's not totally a working solution so I don't want to mislead anyone else but you definitely got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, after some further searching I found with the `dependsOn` in the constructor, it needs to be an array not just a list of strings:

```
task taskName(dependsOn:
            ['otherTask1','otherTask2']){}
```

I don't know why the `dependsOn` method failed but I have something that works.

Comment: Actually, `[]` is the Groovy notation for lists. The whole constructor argument is just a map, where `dependsOn` is one key. After the key comes a `:`, followed by the entry value. At the next `,` a new entry starts. This is why you need a list to collect all task names.